# Как размещать элементы друг под другом в Android?

Tags: android

Как размещать элементы друг под другом в Android? В html например просто:

```
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
```

а вот как второй RelativeLayout в Android разместить ниже? Сейчас он накладывается на первый...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TextView
            android:text="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TextView
            android:text="2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Лично я вижу три варианта решения вашей проблемы:

1. Использовать главный макет типа - `LinearLayout`:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical">

   <RelativeLayout
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent">

           <TextView
               android:text="1"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
       </RelativeLayout>

       <RelativeLayout
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent">

           <TextView
               android:text="2"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
       </RelativeLayout>

   </LinearLayout>
   ```

суть я думаю будет понятна приблизительно.

2. Второй вариант - использовать главный макет типа `RelativeLayout` где указать что второй вью элемент находится под первым:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@color/white">

   <RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:layout_below="id первого relative layout">

       <TextView
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="1"
           app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
   </RelativeLayout>

   <RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent">

       <TextView
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="2"
           app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
   </RelativeLayout>
   ```

НО если у вас в ваших Relative layout будет только textview то можно убрать обертку за ненадобностью  (это лично мое субъективное мнение).

3. Использовать constraint layout и там тоже настроить все по принципу второго варианта.

Один из вариантов предложенных мной должен помочь. Если не получится что-то - пишите и мы постараемся помочь.

Comment: @Streletz, уточните пожалуйста что вы имеете в виду, нельзя использовать relative_layout как главный?

Comment: @Andrew Goroshko, спасибо Вам большое! В качестве главного макета стал использовать `LinearLayout` и всё работает как нужно :) Только код подправьте, пожалуйста, а то он частично отображается

Comment: @Streletz с каких пор RelativeLayout deprecated ?

Comment: @MartinezToni, я вот тоже пытаюсь уточнить что имелось в виду, а то не очень понятно :)

Comment: Ответ всем хорош. Только следовало бы упомянуть, что `RelativeLayout`сейчас всё-таки устаревший подход (хотя официально он ещё не  `deprecated`), который пришёл из Java SE (если не ошибаюсь). Использовать его можно, но лучше всё-таки либо `LinearLayout`, либо `ConstraintLayout`, либо `TableLayout`.

Comment: @Streletz, на мой взгляд если сравнивать то `ConstraintLayout` это более мощное решение чем `RelativeLayout` но если задача не будет использовать все мощности, то можно использовать relativelayout, но в любом случае спасибо за замечание и уточняющую информацию по вашему комментарию :)

Comment: @Streletz и AndrewGoroshko, исходя из вашего короткого диалога, должен вам напомнить, что RelativeLayout использовать не рекомендуется по причине его ресурсо затратности, в таком случае он будет хуже десяти LinearLayout одном в одном (информация из просторв сети), а вот ConstraintLayout по заявлению гугла будет выгоднее чем использовать два LinearLayout-а. Да и в целом он проще, хотя на первый взгляд так может и не показаться.

Comment: @Valeriy, я пока с constraint_layout не смог разобраться к сожалению :(

Comment: Зря))) Загляните на стартАндроид, там неплохие есть уроки. После того как разьерётесь, будете думать: зачем вы мучались последний год)

Comment: `RelativeLayout` рассчитывает вложенные элементы дважды всегда, `LinearLayout` делает то же самое если используете `weight_sum`. Вот и все минусы, которые умножаются при вложении контейнеров.
У `ConstraintLayout` во вложениях нет нужды. Отсюда и плюсы.

Answer (score 1):

Непонятно зачем одиночные контролы вообще вкладывать в контейнеры?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <TextView
    android:text="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  <TextView
    android:text="2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```